# Disabling UITextView Kerning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm trying to disable any kind of kerning in UITextView 
Somehow in arabic letters the text view kern the letters to fit the line but it just ruin the whole word, here's an examples:
[image]

textview has white background, and the code is:

```
NSString *aya =[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.tx.text  = aya;
[cell.tx sizeToFit];
cell.tx.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 265, cell.tx.frame.size.height);
cell.tx.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

also tried to set NSMutableAttributedString NSKernAttributeName value but didn't work,,

---------------------
**Edit:**
 This is the code for Kern Attribute:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;
attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:aya];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                         value:@0.0
                         range:NSMakeRange(0,[aya length])];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                         value:font
                         range:NSMakeRange(0,[aya length])];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrapStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
paragrapStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                         value:paragrapStyle
                         range:NSMakeRange(0,[aya length])];
[cell.tx setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Comment: NSKernAttributeName appears to be the standard way to do this... do you have the code that didn't work?

Comment: @stevesliva I'll append it to the question,,,

Comment: Adding NSKernAttributeName messes the lines heights and strangely they are not fixed also it still kern the words...

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack and I'm not near a computer to try it, but give this a shot:

1. Set the `tx`'s `text` property

   ```
   [tx setText:aya];
   ```
2. Create an NSMutableAttributedString from the text view's text

   ```
   NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[tx attributedText] mutableCopy];
   ```
3. Set the kern attribute on the attributed string

   ```
   [attrStr setAttributes:@{ NSKernAttributeName: @(0.f) }
                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrStr length])];
   ```
4. Set the `attrStr` back on `tx`

   ```
   [tx setAttributedText:attrStr];
   ```

This will (hopefully) preserve the attributes UITextView infers from your NSString.

Comment: thanks, I tried it and unfortunately its still kern letters, it seems like theres some fonts in arabic does not get effected so I ended up  with another font that didn't kern, the font name is LateefRegAAT.ttf,, thanks any way.